# How can I get my entity framework Entities object to inherit from DBContext instead of ObjectContext when using the database first approach?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

My ultimate goal is to have a dry base repository that I can override if needed, Im going off of an example where the developer had functions like:

```
Public Overridable Function [Get](id As Guid) As T Implements IRepositoryBase(Of T).Get
        Return Me.mDbSet.Find(id)
End Function
```

Where mDbSet is from [DatabaseName]Entities.Set(Of T)()

The developer I'm copying used the code first approach so their [DatabaseName]Entities inherits from DbContext whereas I generated mine from the database so it inherits from ObjectContext.

I am looking to make my [DatabaseName]Entities inherit from DbContext without using the code first approach or an alternative way to make the equivalent get by id function using generics.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [DbContext Generator T4 template](http://i4.visualstudiogallery.msdn.s-msft.com/73679ae5-e358-4e76-a538-c7b5e04ac073) instead of default code (or POCO T4) generation used by Entity designer.

Comment: Thanks, also I figured out that in the designer you can right click -> "Add new code generation item..." -> "Online templates" and the above mentioned is right in the list!